# Create slick slider with button that opens modal

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, slick.js

**Updated (see bottom)**

I'm creating a testimonial slider with slick slider, but I need a modal inside every slide.

I have a custom post type 'Testimonials' (English for 'getuigenissen') that has multiple ACF: title, name, function, image and video. I want to show a button on every slide that opens a modal with the video attached to that specific testimonial. The only way I could think of to do this, is to create a modal-div for every testimonial, but I think that creates a lot of unnecessary code.

**PHP-code (I display the testimonials with a shortcode)**

```
function dfib_getuigenissen_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'getuigenissen',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <div class="block__getuigenissen">
            <div class="getuigenissen__wrapper">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="getuigenis__item" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('getuigenis_foto') ?>');">
                        <h2><?php _e( 'Getuigenissen', 'copro' ) ?></h2>
                        <div class="getuigenis__inner">
                            <p class="getuigenis__quote"><?php the_field('getuigenis_getuigenis'); ?></p>
                            <p class="getuigenis__info"><?php the_field('getuigenis_naam');?>, <?php the_field('getuigenis_functie'); ?></p>
                            <a class="getuigenis__video" href=""><?php _e( 'Bekijk de volledige video-getuigenis', 'copro' ) ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="getuigenis_modal">
                        <div class="modal__inner">
                            <?php the_field('getuigenis_video'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'getuigenissen', 'dfib_getuigenissen_shortcode' );
```

What is the best way to set this up and how can I get the right modal to open?

**Update:**
This is what I have so far, the modal works, but the src returns unknown.
see demo: https://copro-staging.dfib.be/

**Testimonials.php**

```
function dfib_getuigenissen_shortcode( $atts ) {
ob_start();
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'getuigenissen',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div class="block__getuigenissen">
        <div class="getuigenissen__wrapper">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $videosrc = get_field('getuigenis_video'); ?>
                <div class="getuigenis__item" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('getuigenis_foto'); ?>');">
                    <svg class="arrow-prev" width="62px" height="124px" viewBox="0 0 62 124" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <path d="M0,0 C34.2416545,0 62,27.7583455 62,62 C62,96.2416545 34.2416545,124 0,124 L0,124 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#93C119"></path>
                            <polyline id="Path-3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.4" transform="translate(26.500000, 61.000000) scale(-1, 1) translate(-26.500000, -61.000000) " points="19 47 34 61 19 75"></polyline>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="getuigenis__inner">
                        <p class="getuigenis__info"><strong><?php the_field('getuigenis_naam');?></strong> - <?php the_field('getuigenis_functie'); ?></p>
                        <p class="getuigenis__quote"><?php the_field('getuigenis_getuigenis'); ?></p>
                        <a class="getuigenis__video" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-src="<?php the_field('getuigenis_video'); ?>" data-target="#myModal">
                            <svg width="59px" height="59px" viewBox="0 0 59 59" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                                <circle id="Oval" stroke="#58595B" stroke-width="1.27776" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="28.86112"></circle>
                                <polygon id="Triangle" fill="#58595B" transform="translate(34.000000, 29.000000) rotate(-270.000000) translate(-34.000000, -29.000000) " points="34 20 43 38 25 38"></polygon>
                            </svg>
                            <?php _e( 'ontdek mijn verhaal', 'copro' ) ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <svg class="arrow-next" width="62px" height="124px" viewBox="0 0 62 124" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <path d="M62,0 L62,124 C27.7583455,124 0,96.2416545 0,62 C0,27.7583455 27.7583455,0 62,0 L62,0 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#93C119"></path>
                            <polyline id="Path-3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.4" points="31 47 46 61 31 75"></polyline>
                    </svg>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-content">                  
              <div class="modal-body">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>        
                  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" src="" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allow="autoplay"></iframe>      
              </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

<?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable;
}
}
add_shortcode( 'getuigenissen', 'dfib_getuigenissen_shortcode' );
```

**testimonials.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        prefooterHeight = $('.block__prefooter').outerHeight();
        prefooterTop = prefooterHeight / 2;
        $('.block__prefooter').css('top', prefooterTop);
    }).trigger('resize');

    $('.getuigenissen__wrapper').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 7000,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        prevArrow: $('.arrow-prev'),
        nextArrow: $('.arrow-next'),
    });

    var videosrc;
    $('.getuigenis__video').click(function() {
        videosrc = $(this).data( "src" );
        console.log(videosrc);
        url = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + videosrc + "?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0";
        console.log(url);
    });

    if ( $('#myModal').hasClass('in') ) {
        $("#video").attr('src',url );
        $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    } else {
        $("#video").attr('src',videosrc);
        $('html').css('overflow', 'visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can make one modal and change the video dynamically with JS

Comment: Could you give some example code on how to do this?

Comment: By multiple you mean using an ACF repeater field containing multiple Videos... ?

Answer (score 1):

you can make one modal and change the video dynamically with JS.

POC: https://codepen.io/MSanbira/pen/NWqqZGW

```js
const videos = {
  title1: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ",
  title2: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eRBOgtp0Hac"
}

const modal = document.querySelector(".video-modal");

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("open-modal")) {
    modal.innerHTML = `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="${videos[e.target.getAttribute("data-video")]}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
    modal.classList.add("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  border: solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video-modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.video-modal.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-modal" data-video="title1">video 1</div>
<div class="open-modal" data-video="title2">video 2</div>

<div class="video-modal"></div>
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but how can I make sure he picks the video that is linked to the post?

Comment: Using this code you just need to set a new data attribute to the link with class "getuigenis__video" in the loop that looks like (data-video="acf video' src") and add to it another class "open-modal"

Answer (score 1):

This a tested code using your snippet. In this solution like in **Matan Sanbira'** Answer, I use a data-src attribute to change the modal block content.
So we don't generate a hard-coded Modal in the loop. You may be using Oembed enabled service like Youtube, Vimeo... But this Method could work even on self-hosted videos.
You just need to change the iFrame code in your modal container to fit to video service requirements.

The php Code:

```
function dfib_getuigenissen_shortcode( $atts ) {
  //PLZ Verify your Assets path for the script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'getuigenissenjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/assets/js/getuigenissen.js' );
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'getuigenissen',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <div class="block__getuigenissen">
            <div class="getuigenissen__wrapper">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php 
                    //Just in case you are using an Ombed field not a URL field or simple text
                    //In this example We don't need Iframe formatting
                    //So we get only the ACF field URL
                    //That's why I added false here
                    $videosrc=get_field('getuigenis_video',false, false);
                    $foto= get_field('getuigenis_foto');
                    ?>
                    <div class="getuigenis__item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($foto['url']); ?>');">
                        <h2><?php _e( 'Getuigenissen', 'copro' ) ?></h2>
                        <div class="getuigenis__inner">
                            <p class="getuigenis__quote"><?php the_field('getuigenis_getuigenis'); ?></p>
                            <p class="getuigenis__info"><?php the_field('getuigenis_naam');?>, <?php the_field('getuigenis_functie'); ?></p>
                            <a class="getuigenis__video" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-src="<?php echo $videosrc ?>" data-target="#myModal"><?php _e( 'Bekijk de volledige video-getuigenis', 'copro' ) ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--I removed your modal code here-->
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">                  
                  <div class="modal-body">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>        
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                    </div>                    
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 

        </div>

    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'getuigenissen', 'dfib_getuigenissen_shortcode' );
```

**getuigenissen.js**

```
function checkYoutube(url) {
    var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
    var matches = url.match(p);
    if(matches){
        return 'https://youtube.com/embed/'+matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var videosrc;  
    $('.getuigenis__video').click(function() {
    validsrc=checkYoutube(videosrc);
    console.log(validsrc);
    });

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#video").attr('src',validsrc+ "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" ); 
    })


    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
//I forgot to add this line to stop the player
//Otherwise it's done player.stop() using Youtube Js API
$("#video").attr("src","");
        $("#video").attr('src',validsrc); 
    }) 
    });
```

If the document ready call is already being used, then you can change it here by a function like `function __videoModal()` and somewhere in your main.js or where you load slick.js, near the document ready you just easily call it by `__videoModal()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
__videoModal();
//other stuff
});
```

You can inspect js codes in this [Working Demo](http://videox.myartsonline.com/getuigenissen/)

Comment: I got this to work with some small tweaks, but I need to make sure I use an embed-url from youtube and nog the 'watch'-url. Is there a way to work around this? I noticed that the video keeps playing when I close the modal, can I stop the video when the modal is closed?

Comment: I also see that the modal backdrop is displayed on top of my modal, is there some css/scss is should use?

Comment: I added a function that validates youtube Url and the missing line where I stop the playing video... :) About this modal, you can give it the same classes you are using for the old design... It's tricky if Css is expecting it to be a child element getuigenis__item ! Can you show a screenshot of your modal? Any css style code?

Comment: We would upload our videos on Vimeo, do I need a different approach then?

Comment: I updated my question with my progress and a link to the demo